# How to do a recursive filename `find` from the shell using a glob pattern with "set braces"

Tags: command-line, bash, unix, find, csh

From the shell, I'd like to recursively search a directory for a given glob pattern. But I want to use set-braces-syntax in my pattern:

```
find ~/path/to/dir -name '*.{h,m}'
```

Here I'd like to recursively find all `.h` and `.m` files located anywhere under the given path.

I gather from reading the [glob documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) these 'set' patterns using curly (`{`) braces are called

> csh(1) style brace expressions

However, my tests using bash and tcsh on macOS 12.3.1 reveal that this set-syntax is not supported by `find`. Reading the [find man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html), I don't see any mention of support for this syntax (maybe I missed it).

How can I accomplish this using this specific 'set' or 'csh-style' curly brace syntax? I'm less interested in work-arounds that use a different syntax.

Comment: `… \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.m' \)`. Call it a work-around, but it's a legitimate (and POSIX) way.

Comment: Good to know. Unfortunately, the only thing I can't give up here is the glob expression containing sets. I really want to find a way to use them specifically (it's for an API, and I find them superior to other options as far as user experience goes).

Comment: "the only thing I can't give up here is the glob expression containing sets" – Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is.

Comment: In Bash: `shopt -s globstar nullglob; for f in ./**/*.{h,m}; do printf '%s\n' "$f"; done`. This is not an answer because from the title I deduce `find` is required.

Answer (score -1):

csh is "c-shell"
Curly braces are generally known as array delimiters and not limited to, nor defined by csh, they form part of *regular expressions*
They may need "escaping" for your shell to parse them properly. (A backslash ahead of them, ie: `\{`...`\}`

Maybe this help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces

Comment: Hm, this is glob syntax, not regular expressions. In this case, escaping the braces does not seem to solve the issue for me. This also returns no output: `find /path/to/dir -name '*.\{h,m\}'`

Comment: mmmm. no. glob is limited to character matching and square brackets. I'm not sure how bash on mac parses things. You could need to escape or abandon the single-ticks, or swap them for quotation marks, or something else. You might need to use the -iname switch on find.

Comment: You are mistaken. Glob syntax can sometimes support this "set" or "braces" syntax. I provided a link above to the man page for glob. Look under ˋGLOB_BRACEˋ. It is documented there. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html